# Style buttons to look like an input type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am having few buttons and a quantity field that currently looks like this:

[image]

This is the code that I am using currently:

```
<Col className="col-3">
     {
          product.quantity > 1 &&
          <button
               onClick={() => decrease(product)}
               className="btn btn-md">
               <i className="fa fa-minus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
     }
     {
          product.quantity === 1 &&
          <button
               onClick={() => removeProduct(product)}
               className="btn btn-md">
               {/* <TrashIcon width={"20px"} /> */}
               <i className="fa fa-trash fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
     }

          &nbsp; <b>{product.quantity}</b> &nbsp;
          <button
          onClick={() => increase(product)}
          className="btn btn-md">
          <i className="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </button>
</Col>
```

I would like to style this button input field to look like this:

[image]

I am not sure if we can combine styled elements with the core business logic here in this case.

Comment: yes you can do that . you are just changing the way how the UI will look . But the rest of the functionalities remains the same . Now you are going to increase the item by clicking on up arrow instead of the + icon .

Comment: Take a look - https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sun-vfg88?file=/src/App2.js